# adding column 2 from a group of text files to 1 text file

Tags: python, text, multiple-columns

I have a group of text files and I am looking to sequentially add the second column from each text file into a new text file. The files are tab delimited and of the following format:

```
name dave
age 35
job teacher
income 30000
```

I have generated a file with the 1st column of one of these files in the place of the second column to hopefully simplify the problem:

```
0 name
0 age 
0 job
0 income
```

I have a large number of these files and would like to have them all in a tab delimited text file such as:

```
name dave mike sue
age 35 28 40
job teacher postman solicitor
income 30000 20000 40000
```

I have a text file containing just the names of all the files called all_libs.txt

so far I have written:

```
#make a sorted list of the file names
with open('all_libs.txt', 'r') as lib:
     people = list([line.rstrip() for line in lib])
     people_s = sorted(people)

i=0

while i< len(people_s):
    with open(people_s[i]) as inf:
        for line in inf:                
            parts = line.split() #split line into parts
            if len(parts) > 1:    #if more than 1 discrete unit in parts
                with open("all_data.txt", 'a') as out_file: #append column2 to all_data
                    out_file.write((parts[1])+"\n")

i=i+1 #go to the next file in the list
```

As each new file is opened I would like to add it as a new column rather than just appending as a new line. Would really appreciate any help? I realize something like SQL would probably make this easy but I have never used it and don't really have time to commit to the learning curve for SQL. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This is a very impractical way to store your data - each record is distributed over all the lines, so it's going to be hard to reconstruct the records when reading the file and (as you've seen) to add records.

You should be using a standard format like [`csv`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) or (even better in a case like this) [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html):

For example, you could save them as CSV like this:

```
name,age,job,income
dave,35,teacher,30000
mike,28,postman,20000
sue,40,solicitor,40000
```

Reading this file:

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open("C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/people.csv", newline="") as infile:
...     reader = csv.DictReader(infile)
...     people = list(reader)
```

Now you have a list of people:

```
>>> people
[{'income': '30000', 'age': '35', 'name': 'dave', 'job': 'teacher'}, 
 {'income': '20000', 'age': '28', 'name': 'mike', 'job': 'postman'}, 
 {'income': '40000', 'age': '40', 'name': 'sue', 'job': 'solicitor'}]
```

which you can access easily:

```
>>> for item in people:
...     print("{0[name]} is a {0[job]}, earning {0[income]} per year".format(item))
...
dave is a teacher, earning 30000 per year
mike is a postman, earning 20000 per year
sue is a solicitor, earning 40000 per year
```

Adding new records now is only a matter of adding them to the end of your file:

```
>>> with open("C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/people.csv", "a", newline="") as outfile:
...    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile,
...                            fieldnames=["name","age","job","income"])
...    writer.writerow({"name": "paul", "job": "musician", "income": 123456,
...                     "age": 70})
```

Result:

```
name,age,job,income
dave,35,teacher,30000
mike,28,postman,20000
sue,40,solicitor,40000
paul,70,musician,123456
```

Or you can save it as JSON:

```
>>> import json
>>> with open("C:/Users/Tim/Desktop/people.json", "w") as outfile:
...     json.dump(people, outfile, indent=1)
```

Result:

```
[
 {
  "income": "30000", 
  "age": "35", 
  "name": "dave", 
  "job": "teacher"
 }, 
 {
  "income": "20000", 
  "age": "28", 
  "name": "mike", 
  "job": "postman"
 }, 
 {
  "income": "40000", 
  "age": "40", 
  "name": "sue", 
  "job": "solicitor"
 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks for your post. Unfortunately its not my data, it comes from someone elses pipeline and this is the format so I need to work around it.

Comment: @user3062260: You wrote "I have these files..." - OK, they are in a suboptimal format, but very easy to read. Then you wrote "I want to have them in a file like this..." - why? My solution deals with the second part, how to aggregate the data in a useful way, and it seems you are the one who can control this part.

Answer (score 0):

```
file_1 = """
name dave1
age 351
job teacher1
income 300001"""

file_2 = """
name dave2
age 352
job teacher2
income 300002"""

file_3 = """
name dave3
age 353
job teacher3
income 300003"""

template = """
0 name
0 age
0 job
0 income"""
```

Assume that the above is read from the files

```
_dict = {}


def concat():
    for cols in template.splitlines():
        if cols:
            _, col_name = cols.split()
            _dict[col_name] = []

    for each_file in [file_1, file_2, file_3]:
        data = each_file.splitlines()
        for line in data:
            if line:
                words = line.split()
                _dict[words[0]].append(words[1])

    _text = ""

    for key in _dict:
        _text += '\t'.join([key, '\t'.join(_dict[key]), '\n'])

    return _text

print concat()
```

OUTPUT

```
job teacher1    teacher2    teacher3    
age 351 352 353 
name    dave1   dave2   dave3   
income  300001  300002  300003
```